# Cannot post data with JQuery and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

I'm new with php. I'm trying to post some input with ajax but it doesn't work.

This is my HTML for input:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <h3>Answer:</h3>
  <div class="input-group">
    <textarea name="q1" id="q1" class="form-control" rows="4" ></textarea>        
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
```

And this is my jquery function to post data:

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
  var q1= $('#q1').val();
  $.ajax({ 
    type: 'post',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: {
    q1: q1              
   },
                  
    success:  function (response) {  
      console.log( response);
     }           
    });
  });
});
```

My test.php is a simple code to display the input:

```html
<?php 
 $q1= $_POST['q1'];
    echo $q1;
?>
```

I don't know why in my test.php I get this error : `Notice: Undefined index: q1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\file\test.php on line 2`

Can anyone tell me where is the issue?

Comment: Are you getting that error when you go directly to test.php in your browser?

Comment: @LeonAves exactly,

Comment: That's expected. When you visit it directly in your browser you aren't posting q1 to test.php. You should try replacing your success function with `function (data) { console.log(data);  }` and check your console.

Comment: @LeonAves I tryed this and i get my input in the console, however i still get the error

Comment: You're never going to not get that error going directly to it in the browser. The PHP is expecting posted data, which you are not sending it when you visit the page directly. The PHP is—for all intents and purposes in this scenario—stateless. It's not going to show the input you gave it in the AJAX request because it doesn't even know that request happened.

Comment: Right! could you tell me what i'm supposed to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: This isn't an issue. You are receiving the data back in the javascript, as expected. Presumably you want to use the data sent back from PHP in the javascript? Why do you need it to appear when you visit the page directly? If you want it to persist over multiple requests, then you will need to look at session storage.

Comment: I want to store data in DB. I treyd session but it doesn't work

Comment: Where is your code for storing data in DB? You have the data in test.php. How did you store data in session? These are other things you need to ask.

Comment: I think the main problem here is your lack of understanding of how HTTP works at its core. I don't think you actually want the value of q1 to show up when you visit test.php, I think you're using that as a metric that your AJAX request succeeded, which you shouldn't be. Take a look at this page: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html (don't bother reading past the section on "Requests and Responses in PHP". It's a really good overview of HTTP fundamentals, and it may help you come at your problem from a different perspective.

Comment: Thank you. It is clear now and it works the way I want

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are trying to post a json data to your php file so jQuery may not create correct payload for your request since you getting `undefined index:q1`. Can you try the code below;

```
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        var q1 = $('#q1').val();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'test.php',
            data : "q1="+q1,
            success : function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @H.Tirit so have checked your browser console's network section to know what test.php returning after request ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('document').ready(function(){

      $("form#data").submit(function(){
          var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); 
          $.ajax({ 
            url: 'url', 
            type: 'POST', 
            data: formData, 
            async: false, 
            success: function (data) 
            { 
              alert(data); 
            }, 
            cache: false, 
            contentType: false, 
            processData: false 
          }); 
         return false; 
         }); 
      });
}
```

```html
    <form id="data" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h3>Answer:</h3>
      <div class="input-group">
        <textarea name="q1" id="q1" class="form-control" rows="4" ></textarea>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
    </form>
```